# Why is {0101, 1010} an equivalence class in this problem?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

I am tasked to show each equivalence class in $\{0,1\}^4$ (means every $4$ bit string made with $0$ and $1$).

We know that they are $2^4 =  16$ different strings you can have.

I thought that for that each equivalence class is defined by having n number 1s in their string. i.e: all strings with one $1$ together, etc...

So looking up the solution we have: $\{0000\} \{0001, 0010, 0100, 1000\} \{0011, 0110, 1100, 1001\} \{0101, 1010\} \{0111,1011,1101,1110\} \{1111\}$.

Why does the equivalence class $\{0101,1010\}$ exists? Why it's not in $\{0011, 0110, 1100, 1001\}$ ?

Comment: In order to speak of an "equivalence class" you must have an "equivalence relation".  Which equivalence relation did you have in mind?  If you mean $S_1\sim S_2\iff $ the two strings have the same number of $1's$, then $\{0101,1010\}$ is not a full equivalence class.

Comment: And if you consider two sequences of bits equivalent when you can obtain one from the other by rotating the bits around, then those are the equivalence classes.

Comment: I'm guessing from your question that maybe you thought that there was exactly one definition of "equivalence" on $\{0,1\}^4$, universally used everywhere? That is not the case. There are many, many equivalence relations that can be defined on that set. I'm also guessing that "having the same number of 1s" was the relation for a *different problem* that you just assumed held for this one too. From the classes you listed, it appears this relation is "are rotations of each other" Thankfully, this is the reason for exercises - to point out flaws in your understanding so you can correct them.